# Intersection of two functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, intersection

Could you please try to find the intersections points of this two functions: 
$ y = x $ and $y=(a+x) \ {\rm e}^ {-2(a+x)} $ with $x\geq0$

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi Ivan, Welcome to MSE! Can you please post the code you have tried.

Comment: Try the Lambert function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: see also [ProductLog](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ProductLog.html)

Comment: The generalization of the Lambert function by Mező http://real.mtak.hu/39795/1/Generalization%20of%20the%20Lambert%20W%20function.pdf is relevant

Comment: @yarchik Looks amazing.

Answer (score 3):

To visualize the pairs of real numbers `{x, a}` that satisfy the equation,

you can use `ContourPlot`:

```
ContourPlot[(a + x) E^(-2 (a + x)) == x, {x, -2, 1}, {a, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

or `RegionPlot` with options `MeshFunctions` + `Mesh`:

```
RegionPlot[True, {x, -2, 1}, {a, 0, 5}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 MeshFunctions -> {(#2 + #) E^(-2 (#2 + #)) - # &}, 
 Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], 
 PlotStyle -> None, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you'll need some constraints on `a`.

```
a = -1;
f[x_] := (a + x) E^(-2 (a + x))
Plot[{x, f[x]}, {x, 0.001, 4}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-2, 1}}]
```

[image]